# Jquery form popup on textarea on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve a form popup/modal when user clicks on the input area below, I have a currency conversion form but I don't know how to connect this form to the input area below:

[image]

[image]

I want to do it just like how datepicker popup appears when you click on the textfield like below:

[image]

How do I achieve the similar behaviour to datepicker?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is here [Tippy.js](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/)

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the modal's click event handler to handle what you click.
2. Build a function to handle what value handler received comes in.
3. Set the function return value to the currency form.

The question seems not obviously told.

So just follow tips above, you should solve this question.